# Why didn't Diaval take the raven form in this scene?

Tags: maleficent, maleficent-mistress-of-evil

In *Maleficent: Mistress of Evil* (2019), not long after Queen Aurora entered into the secret chapel, we can see here that Diaval is struggling to climb the castle.

[image: Diaval climbing the castle wall]

Why didn't Diaval take the raven form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diaval can't change his form by himself, it's Maleficent that chooses when and into what to transform him. I don't recall it being said directly in the movies, however, there are several scenes across both movies that make that fact clear.

As an example, when she turns him into a wolf in *Maleficent (2014)*:

> **Diaval:** How could you do that to me?
>   **Maleficent:** You said anything I need.
>   **Diaval:** Yeah, but not a dog!
>   **Maleficent:** It was a wolf, not a dog.
>   **Diaval:** It’s the same thing! They’re dirty, vicious, and they hunt birds.
>   **Maleficent:** Fine, next time I will turn you into a mealy worm.
>   **Diaval:** Well, I’ll be a mealy worm, gladly. Anything but a filthy, stinking…
>
> [Maleficent turns him back into a raven before he can finish his
>   sentence.]

There is also the scene in *Maleficent: Mistress of Evil (2019)* when they are walking through the castle and Diaval asks Maleficent if **she** ever thought about turning him into a bear:

> **Diaval:** Did you ever consider turning me into a bear? I think I’d be quite impressive. Look at their claws…

---

**So, to answer your question: he couldn't.**